# Every time I send data from android app to esp32 module, it arrives as an "EmptyInput"

Tags: java, android, json, http-post, esp32

I need to send data in json format from the android app to the esp32 wifi module ("arduino").

The android app succesfully sends the data in proper json format... the esp32 module knows its receiving something but it always arrives as an empty input and gives me an error due to it.

On the other hand, when I send/receive data from a flask server to the esp32 module it works fine. Same with sending/receiving data from flask server to android app... Any suggestions or am I doing something wrong between the two?

This is part of a "big project" for class and has over 2 months of work into it, so I really need this to work here. Thanks!

I have tried sending simple strings like "hey", where the content type is set as "plain" and it still arrives as an empty string to the esp32...

**I have the following in the esp32 module:**

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include "AsyncJson.h"

const char* ssid = "wifi_ssid";                //changed these for the post
const char* password = "wifi_password";        //changed these for the post
const unsigned long connectionTimeout = 10000;

AsyncWebServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.print("Connecting to Wifi...");

  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi. IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  //other code stuff...

  // Start server
  //other server.on() stuff...
  server.on("/brew_coffee", HTTP_POST, handleBrewCoffee);
  
  server.begin();
}

void handleBrewCoffee(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  if (request != nullptr) {

    String clientIPAddress = request->client()->remoteIP().toString();

    // Here I receive the data and print it
    String recipeReceived = request->arg("application/json");
    Serial.print("\n" + clientIPAddress);
    Serial.print(" sent string: ");
    Serial.println(recipeReceived);

    DynamicJsonDocument jsonDoc(16386);
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(jsonDoc, recipeReceived);

    //This is where I get the EmptyInput error
    if (error) {
      Serial.print("Failed to parse JSON: ");
      Serial.println(error.c_str());
      recipeReceived = "not: " + clientIPAddress;

    } else{
        //Extracting json data
        const char* username = jsonDoc["username"];
        const char* user_ip = jsonDoc["user_ip"];
        const char* user_id = jsonDoc["user_id"];
        const char* name = jsonDoc["name"];
        //I do rest of the data likewise

        // Print the coffee information
        Serial.println("\nCoffee Information:");
        Serial.print("username: "); Serial.println(username);
        Serial.print("user_id: "); Serial.println(user_id);
        Serial.print("Coffee Name: "); Serial.println(name);
        //I do rest of the data likewise
        
        recipeReceived = "Coffee Received";
      }
  }
}
```

**This is the function in my android app (from android studio) that sends the data:**

```
    public String makeServiceCallPostJSON(String reqUrl, String username, String user_ip, int user_id, String name, more params...) {

        String response = null;
        try {

            //This url is the same as the esp32 with its proper endpoint
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
            jsonParams.put("username", username);
            jsonParams.put("user_ip", user_ip);
            jsonParams.put("user_id", user_id);
            jsonParams.put("name", name);
            //I do rest likewise


            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            System.out.println(jsonParams.toString());

            conn.getOutputStream().write(jsonParams.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

            // Convert the InputStream in a String
            response = convertStreamToString(in);

            System.out.println("This is what i got... " + response);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }
```

**This is the output I get in the esp32 module**

> ###.###.#.### (client address) Sent string:
> Failed to parse JSON: EmptyInput

**These are the prints I get in android studio's Logcat**

> {"username":"guest","user_ip":"###.###.#.###","user_id":1,"name":"Coffee B", ...}
> This is what i got... not

The user_ip is the same as the client address printed in the esp32 output. Which further proofs its "receiving" something even if its empty...

Comment: I would first try and print the entire "request" to see how it's formed or to be more precise how ESPAsyncWebServer.h is formatting the "args" key:values. You may find that the json is already split in args to something like request->arg("username"), request->arg("user_id")

Comment: I tried your suggestion and didnt work either... but I just found an alternative way to do it and it works now... I am using WebServer.h now and havent had any issues... its a bit simlpler to use as well.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the following libraries always gave me an empty string when trying to send something from the mobile app to the esp32:
ESP8266WebServer
AsyncWebServer_ESP32_W5500
ESPAsyncWebServer
ESPAsyncWebSrv

Note: these worked when communicating with something else like a flask server in python... I still don't know what the issue is with the mobile app.

This one worked perfectly with both the mobile app and the flask server... I didn't really change anything of what I was doing except for minor sintax changes for the following library:
WebServer

Here is how it looks:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>

String ssid = "wifi_ssid";
String password = "wifi_password";
WebServer server(80);

void setup(){

    Serial.print("Connecting to Wifi...");
    
    // Connect to Wi-Fi
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(1000);
    
    }
    
    server.on("/brew_coffee", HTTP_POST, handleBrewCoffee);
    server.begin();

}

void handleBrewCoffee() {

    if (server.hasArg("plain")) {

        String recipeReceived = server.arg("plain");
        Serial.println("Received JSON data:");
        Serial.println(recipeReceived);
        DynamicJsonDocument jsonDoc(1024);
        DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(jsonDoc, recipeReceived);

        if (error) {

            Serial.print("Failed to parse JSON: ");
            Serial.println(error.c_str());
            recipeReceived = "not";
    
        } else{

            const char* username = jsonDoc["username"];
            //same for the rest
    
            Serial.println("Coffee Information:");
            Serial.print("username: "); Serial.println(username);
            //same for the rest
      
            recipeReceived = "Coffee Received";

        }

        server.send(200, "text/plain", recipeReceived);

    }

}
```